# Can we apply propensity scores or the Miettinen multivariate confounder score to meta-regression?

Tags: regression, meta-analysis, meta-regression, propensity-scores

Meta-regression is an established approach to adjust at the study-level the results of a systematic review and meta-analysis not encompassing patient-level data. It basically consists on a regression model with study-wise weighting depending on study precision.

One of the main drawbacks of meta-regression is however its inefficiency and need for relatively large samples of studies.

Building upon existing theoretical and applied research on [propensity scores](http://www.contemporaryclinicaltrials.com/article/S1551-7144(11)00111-X/abstract) (with regression adjustment) and the Miettinen multivariate confounder score (as spelled out in [Miettinen OS, Stratification by a multivariate confounder score, Am J Epidemiol 1976;104:609-20](http://aje.oxfordjournals.org/content/104/6/609.long)
) in individual clinical trials, I am wondering whether we could apply such an approach to meta-regression.

Of course, a small meta-analysis (i.e. including few trials) will typically be unable to generate stable and meaningful propensity or Miettinen scores, so the effort might be futile.

Comment: Are you trying to address the problem of having (too) many moderator variables? Your suggestion would not, I think, do much about the problem of imprecise primary studies.

Comment: @mdewey Yes, the main issue is the need to reduce the risk of overfitting due to too many moderators in meta-regression.

Comment: The multivariable (it's not _multivariate_) confounder score violates some statistical principles.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I would like to correct multivariate into multivariable, as conceptually that's what it is... but I checked the original Miettinen's paper and he used that term...

Comment: He shouldn't have

Comment: @FrankHarrell You are 100% right